# Using my home router's IP address from anywhere in the world

Tags: router, vpn, ip

I am moving to Spain and I want to use my UK router's IP address via VPN. My knowledge on this is limited, and when I search VPN routers, it seems to only point to specialised routers which connect to a VPN. I want to use the internet on my machine in Spain with my router's IP address in UK. Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.top10vpn.com/vpn-setup/home-vpn-server/

Comment: You can access your home computer via VPN from anywhere - I do this.  Using Internet this way will be noticeably slower. I just use the local internet.

Comment: And I hope you're aware you'll be paying for both services.

Comment: unfortunately, "VPN", being a low level technology, is used in many ways for a wide array of purposes, and that makes it difficult to learn about the basics. yes it is possible to do what you want, though it will have some impact on internet performance.  basically you want to set up a point-to-site connection (the "point" being your devices in spain, and your "site" being your home network in the UK). this is easiest if your home router supports a common VPN server like OpenVPN.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, and depending on your resources and budget there are many ways of achieving it.

I would argue one of the easiest ways would (if you don't already have one) be to get an ethernet router capable of running dd-wrt or similar and setting this up as an OpenVPN server.   You would either replace your existing router with this one, or set this router up as a DMZ - ie forward all traffic on to it from your main router.  You will need to make sure that traffic originating through the VPN interface is NAT'd.

There are other ways to do this, including putting a box behind the existing router (maybe a Raspberry Pi?) and then using a proxy server or VPN on this.  It is less elegant then upgrading your router.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest option would be

1. Get [GL-iNet](https://openvpn.net/) router based on your requirements (see mini or travel routers). Gl router firmware based on open source OpenWRT with much nicer GUI and some handy features
2. Connect router via Ethernet cable (WAN port) to your home router (LAN port) or via WI-FI. Find newly connect glinet router ip and go to it, complete necessary setup when prompted if login first time
3. Initiate OpenVPN or WireGuard client on Gl-iNet router and export server settings to preferred vpn app on your computer, recommending apps for [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) and [WireGuard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wireguard/id1451685025?mt=12) on mac